# regex for SQL Server datetime format

Tags: php, sql-server, regex, date, datetime

I've got a tricky corner case that I need help with writing a regex to validate [Microsoft SQL Server supported datetime/offset formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

In particular, this is a valid `datetimeoffset`

```
2015-11-12 14:29:08 -07:00
```

However, here's a common, but unsupported format (no colon in timezone offset):

```
2015-11-12 14:29:08 -0700
```

I can't quite figure out how to invalidate that pattern match without breaking the other accepted formats. Here are some sample unit tests:

```
<?php

$tests = [
    '12 months' =>                  false,
    '12:12:12' =>                  'datetime',
    '12/12/2012' =>                'datetime',
    '12/12/2012 12:12:12' =>       'datetime',
    '2012-12-12' =>                'datetime',
    '2012-12-12 12:12:12' =>       'datetime',
    '2012-12-12T12:12:12+05:00' => 'datetimeoffset',
    '2015-11-12 14:29:08 -0700' =>  false,
    '2015-11-12 14:29:08 -07:00' =>'datetimeoffset',
];

foreach($tests as $format => $datatype){
    if (preg_match('/^[\s\dT+:\/-]*$/', $format) !== 1){
        $match = false;
    } else {
        $match = true;
    }

    if($datatype == $match){
        echo "pass - $format\n";
    } else {
        echo "FAIL - $format\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not testing "formats". You're simply testing for the presence/absensce of certain characters. You cannot "fix" your code, because it's fundamentally wrong. - the "bad" format uses the EXACT SAME characters that all the others do, so it's literally impossible to tell them apart.

Comment: @MarcB This is a somewhat contrived example distilled for an MCVE. I'm taking in data from disparate sources with a pre-validated variety of datetime formats, so I'm just trying to filter down a subset for this particular DBMS. How would you suggest to approach the problem?

Comment: Have a look at the Carbon library. [carbon.nesbot.com](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation)

Comment: you have to test each specific format, e.g. try to parse the date by something like `create_date_from_format()` and see if it gets through successfully. otherwise it'd be the realworld equivalent of testing for  bread by seeing if you have milk+eggs+flour - but waffles and pancakes will match that as well